# powershell: compare specific columns of CSV files and return entire row of differences

Tags: csv, powershell, file-comparison

I have 2 CSV files I'd like to compare. They both have multiple columns of different data but they also both have a column with IP addresses. Call them $log1 and $log2

I am trying to compare the files. If an IP from $log1 is found in $log2 I would like an output file that has the *entire row* of data from the match of $log2...

When I use:

`Compare-Object -Property 'IP address' -ReferenceObject $log1 -DifferenceObject $log2`

It returns only the 'IP address' column and the SideIndicator.

I think I'm barking up the wrong tree here, can anyone offer some advice?

Comment: `$log2|Where-Object 'IP address' -in $log1.'IP address'`

Comment: Try adding the `-PassThru` flag to your command.

Answer (score 0):

I would try another approach :

```
$log1,$log2 | group-object -Property 'IP address' | where {$_.count -eq 2}
```

In the result you will find a `group` property with the two lines.

Answer (score 0):

> "Try adding the -PassThru flag to your command."
>    - Dave Sexton

This works. I exported the results to CSV and sorted by the SideIndicator when I opened the file (don't think you can get PS to sort by SideIndicator).

Thanks Dave.

There's probably more ways to accomplish this, as noted by others but this achieved my goal.

Comment: *don't think you can get PS to sort by SideIndicator* Does `sort SideIndicator` not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This script will compare your both csv files and writhe output for each double ip address found.

```
#import your csv files
$csv1 = Import-Csv "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\csv\csv1.csv"
$csv2 = Import-Csv "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\csv\csv2.csv"

#Compare both csv files (.ip corresponds to your column name for your ip address in the csv file )
$compare = Compare-Object $csv1.ip $csv2.ip -IncludeEqual | ? {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=="}

if ($compare) {

    foreach ($ip in $compare.InputObject) {
    Write-Output "IP $ip exist in both csv files"
    }

}
Else 
    {
        Write-Output "Double ip not found"
    }
```